# Error after uninstalling TypeScript 2.3 RC in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I see the following error in Visual Studio when trying to build a TypeScript project.

`The specified task executable "tsc.exe" could not be run. Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1., Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

This only occurred after installing TS 2.3 RC, then uninstalling, and then trying to repair my installation. Repairing doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few `.dll`s that aren't getting removed during uninstallation and are causing problems. To fix this issue delete all `.dll`s inside `C:\Program Files (or X86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript` and try to repair VS again.

This should result in the base version of TypeScript for your version of VS being installed (1.8 in the case of VS 2015). You can then install your desired version of TS on top of that.